# after assigning a function to a 'pointer to function' why does it print 1 instead of the address of the assigned function

Tags: c++, pointers

when we create a pointer 'int (*ptr)()' and assign it to a function 'foo', it should store the address of that function. But when i try to print the pointer ptr it displays 1 instead of the address of the foo. Why is that ?

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(){
    return 2019;
}

int main(){

    int (*ptr)() = foo;

    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Its actually because there is no specific overload for a function pointer type. It gets converted to a `bool` which is then displayed as 1 (since it is non-zero).

Comment: on Visual Studio output is in fact the adress of the function.

Comment: Put `(void*)` before `ptr`.